# How to use cProfile with nosetest --with-profile?

Tags: python, nose, cprofile

> nosetest --with-profile --profile-stats-file output

The output can't read by runsnake, because nosetest uses hotshot, if I want to generate a file that can be read with runsnake, I need to convert it so:

> st = hotshot.stats.load('output')
>
> st.dump_stats('output_new')

Could I run the test with cProfile directly for read with runsnake?

Comment: seems weird that nosetests would choose hotshot

Comment: Maybe this will be handy: https://github.com/msherry/nose-cprof ? (I did not try this myself yet)

Answer (score 11):

Evolving on the answer of @squid, you can use a *nose* plugin called [`nose-cprof`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-cprof) to replace the nose default profiler, hotshot, with cProfile.

To install it:

```
pip install nose-cprof
```

Then call nose like this:

```
nosetests --with-cprofile
```

It should generate a cProfile output file, that you can then analyze with tools like `runsnakerun`.

Comment: I've not had luck with getting the plugin to work: pip install looks fine, but when running --with-cprofile, the flags are not found. I went for the --with-profile instead.

Answer (score 4):

@cihanpesend's answer didn't quite work for me (cProfile couldn't find 'nosetests'), but I did have success on Linux using:

```
python -m cProfile -o profile.out `which nosetests` .
```

The resulting output works fine in runsnake.

(Presumably on Windows you could replace `which nosetests` with the hard-coded path to your nosetests top-level python script.)

I *think* you are right that the output from nosetests' hotshot profiler is not compatible with runsnake. Certainly the two don't play nice together out of the box for me either.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have info about nosetest except it is python project. So;

```
python -m cProfile -o outputfile nosetest
```

Then,

```
runsnake outputfile
```

RunSnakeRun is extremly useful to visualize profiler.

Note: to run `runsnake`, you must install wx and numpy.

update: from omikron's comment; runsnakerun can not support python3 profile output. (i didn't try)

Comment: It should be noted that `runsnakerun` doesn't work when profiling Python 3 code and seem to be not maintained anymore. Instead I recommend to use `pyprof2calltree` with `kcachegrind`.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try nose-cprof plugin:　https://github.com/msherry/nose-cprof

It replaces hotshot with cProfile

Answer (score 0):

With `pyprof2calltree`:

```
$ pip install pyprof2calltree
$ nosetests --with-cprofile --profile-stats=profile.out tests/
$ pyprof2calltree -i profile.out -k
```

With `xdot`:

```
$ sudo apt install xdot
$ gprof2dot -f pstats profile.out | dot -Tpng -o profile.png
```